# Mysql AES_DECRYPT() function not working in Django raw query

Tags: python, mysql, django, encryption

When I use MySql function AES_DECRYPT() in a raw query in Django, this function didn't work. My code is like this:

```
sql = "select AES_DECRYPT(myfield, mykey) as ssn from mytable "
people_list = Peopletable.objects.raw(sql)
for p in people_list:
    print p.ssn
```

It printed out None, which means AES_DECRYPT() didn't work. But if I run the query in python side then I get what I need. I tried other mysql functions like SUBSTR() and they worked perfectly. Seems like only this AES_DECRYPT() doesn't work in Django. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not a Django prog, but does `Peopletable.objects.raw(sql)` actually execute the query?

Comment: yes, it does. I can get the values of all other fields, except the one from AES_DECRYPT() function.

Comment: Did you encrypt that column using MYSQL AES_ENCRYPT?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually mean it doesn't work just that result of AES_DECRYPT(myfield, mykey) is None (null).

If [AES_DECRYPT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt) detects invalid data or incorrect padding, it returns NULL. However, it is possible for AES_DECRYPT() to return a non-NULL value (possibly garbage) if the input data or the key is invalid.

Try to run same query directly on database it will probably have same result.